# Jasmine can't find a injected var inside injected module

Tags: javascript, angularjs, testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have the following scenario:

A test class with the goal is `validate` my directive...

```
describe('Directive Spec', function() {

    var $compile, $rootScope, directives;

    beforeEach(module('ui-first', 'ui-first.directive'));

    beforeEach(module(function(_$provide_) {
        _$provide_.value('$commons');
    }));

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
        $compile = _$compile_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
        directive = $compile("<ui-pop-dir></ui-pop-dir>")($rootScope);
        $rootScope.$digest();
    }));

    it('blablabla', function() {...});
});
```

`ui-first` is my module and `ui-first.directive` my template declaration in `karma.conf.js`.

In my directive, i have a `inject` declaration for my controller...

```
Controller.$inject = ['$scope', '$commons'];
```

Inside my `$commons`, i have an `injector`...

```
var promisseT = $injector.get('promisseT');
```

When i run my tests, Jasmine can't find my `$commons` and tests fail...

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$commons.$promisseT') (line 34)
Controller@C:/Users/user.user/git/gitlab/src/pop.directive.js:34:33
```

Any Ideas? :(

Comment: Shouldn't it be _$provide_.value('$commons', something_here); Ie you have to provide it a value, like a spy object.

Comment: @rrd - using `_$provide_.value('$commons', 'promiseT')`, my stacktrace change to a method call, like this: `TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating '$commons.$promiseT()')`. Error continues... :(